# Get last part after number regex python

Tags: python, regex, text-processing

I have always 2 numbers in between and I want to extract everything before 3 so `Salvatore` and everything after 2 `Abdulla`
For example I have the following:

```
txt = "Salvatore32Abdulla"
first = re.findall("^\D+", txt)
last = re.search(,txt)
```

Expected result:

```
first = 'Salvatore'
last = 'Abdulla'
```

I can get the first part, but after 2 I can't get the `last` part

Comment: Remove `^` from your pattern and it'll work. See [here](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEolaukokTBVkEpODGnLLEkvyjV2MgxKaU0JydRiasCKFGUqpeWmZeSmJOjoRTjoq2kowDUoMlVUJSZV6JRofn/PwA)

Comment: Oh wow, Thank you sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Why am I not getting the expected results?

You currently have one issue with your regex and one with your code.

Your regex contains `^`, which anchors it to the start of the string. This will only allow you to match `Salvatore`. You're using `findall` (which is the appropriate choice if you change the regex to simply `\D+`), but right now it's only getting one result.

The second `re.search` call is not needed as you can capture *first* and *last* with the `findall` given an appropriate pattern (see below).

---

#### How do I fix it?

[See code in use here](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEolaukokTBVkEpODGnLLEkvyjV2MgxKaU0JydRiasCKFGUqpeWmZeSmJOjoRTjoq2kowDUoMlVUJSZV6JRofn/PwA)

```
import re
txt = "Salvatore32Abdulla"
x = re.findall("\D+", txt)
print(x)
```

Result:

```
['Salvatore', 'Abdulla']
```

Comment: I suggested a close variant of your solution. Hence, voted you up.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation

Answer (score 2):

You could also do this in a single line by slightly changing the solution suggested by @ctwheels as follows. I would suggest you to use `re.findall` as that gets the job done with a single blow.

```py
import re
txt = "Salvatore32Abdulla"
```

#### Option-1

Single line extraction of the non-numeric parts.

```py
first, last = re.findall("\D+", txt)
print((first, last))
```

```
('Salvatore', 'Abdulla')
```

#### Option-2

If you would (for some reason) also want to keep track of the number in between:

```py
first, num, last = re.findall("(\D+)(\d{2})(\D+)", txt)
print((first, num, last))
```

```
('Salvatore', '32', 'Abdulla')
```

#### Option-3

As an extension of **Option-2** and considering the text with a form `'Salvatore####...###Abdulla'`, where `####...###` denotes a continuous block of digits separating the non-numeric parts and you may or may not have any idea of how many digits could be in-between, you could use the following:

```py
first, num, last = re.findall("(\D+)(\d*)(\D+)", txt)
print((first, num, last))
```

```
('Salvatore', '32', 'Abdulla')
```

Comment: I think this is the best answer.  Using Regex's built in grouping mechanism clean and simple. It allows you to also not be too worried about extra data being placed into the code.  In the other answer, it allowed the array to expand to cover an  infinite example, but this one keeps the result set explicitly to what was requested

Comment: @GigaMeta If you think it helped, could you please also **vote up** this answer? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex like this:

```py
txt = "Salvatore32Abdulla"
regex = r"(\D+)\d\d(\D+)"

match = re.match(regex, txt)
first = match.group(1)
last = match.group(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Part after last digit:

```
match = re.search(r'\D+$',txt)
if match:
    print(match.group())
```

See [Python proof](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEolYurpKJEwVZBKTgxpyyxJL8o1djIMSmlNCcnUYkrN7EkOQMoWZSqV5yaWJScoVGkHuOiraKuA9SkyZWZpgBWYcWlAAQFRZl5JRpgAb30ovzSAg1NTa7//wE) | [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/kBUeSB/1).

**Results**: `Abdulla`

**EXPLANATION**

```py
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \D+                      non-digits (all but 0-9) (1 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```